# SQL window function replace max by correspondent string

Tags: sql, aggregate, partitioning

I have a table named `products`:

```
+---+------------+----------------+---------------+
| Id|product_name|product_category|product_revenue|
+---+------------+----------------+---------------+
|  1|      orange|           friut|         170000|
|  2|       apple|           friut|         300000|
|  3|       peach|           friut|          98000|
|  4|      banana|           friut|         285000|
|  5|    cucumber|       vegetable|         451000|
|  6|      tomato|       vegetable|         512000|
|  7|       salad|       vegetable|         281000|
|  8|     cabbage|       vegetable|          85000|
|  9|        coke|           drink|         687000|
| 10|       fanta|           drink|         258000|
| 11|      sprite|           drink|         432000|
| 12|       pepsi|           drink|         661000|
+---+------------+----------------+---------------+
```

I perform this SQL query:

```
SELECT *, max(product_revenue) OVER w AS max  
FROM products 
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY product_category) 
ORDER BY Id
```

And as a result a get this table with new **max** column which represents max **product_revenue** in each **product_category**:

```
+---+------------+----------------+---------------+------+
| Id|product_name|product_category|product_revenue|   max|
+---+------------+----------------+---------------+------+
|  1|      orange|           friut|         170000|300000|
|  2|       apple|           friut|         300000|300000|
|  3|       peach|           friut|          98000|300000|
|  4|      banana|           friut|         285000|300000|
|  5|    cucumber|       vegetable|         451000|512000|
|  6|      tomato|       vegetable|         512000|512000|
|  7|       salad|       vegetable|         281000|512000|
|  8|     cabbage|       vegetable|          85000|512000|
|  9|        coke|           drink|         687000|687000|
| 10|       fanta|           drink|         258000|687000|
| 11|      sprite|           drink|         432000|687000|
| 12|       pepsi|           drink|         661000|687000|
+---+------------+----------------+---------------+------+
```

The question is **how can I get correspondent product_name instead of digits**? 
So I would like to get this:

```
+---+------------+----------------+---------------+---------+
| Id|product_name|product_category|product_revenue|   max   |
+---+------------+----------------+---------------+---------+
|  1|      orange|           friut|         170000|apple    |
|  2|       apple|           friut|         300000|apple    |
|  3|       peach|           friut|          98000|apple    |
|  4|      banana|           friut|         285000|apple    |
|  5|    cucumber|       vegetable|         451000|tomato   |
|  6|      tomato|       vegetable|         512000|tomato   |
|  7|       salad|       vegetable|         281000|tomato   |
|  8|     cabbage|       vegetable|          85000|tomato   |
|  9|        coke|           drink|         687000|coke     |
| 10|       fanta|           drink|         258000|coke     |
| 11|      sprite|           drink|         432000|coke     |
| 12|       pepsi|           drink|         661000|coke     |
+---+------------+----------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: Does your DBMS support `FIRST_VALUE`?  Try `FIRST_VALUE(product_name) OVER (PARTITION BY product_category ORDER BY product_revenue DESC)`

Comment: "vegetable" and "drink" are not product names in your data.

Comment: Thanx, @GordonLinoff! My, mistake, I've corrected **max** column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

```
SELECT p.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN maxpr = product_revenue THEN product_name END) OVER (PARTITION BY product_category)
FROM (SELECT p.*, max(product_revenue) OVER w AS maxpr
      FROM products p WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY product_category)
     ) p
ORDER BY Id;
```

There are other methods as well, depending on your database.